# How to prevent floating divs from overflowing into one another with absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I am wanting to show overflowing text in a div. I want it to start from the middle of the div and go down from there. I also would like it to push the next row down so all the text can show and not go into the other div.

Here is a current [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfe9w3uc/10/) I am working on to get this to work, but I am stuck

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="div1">
      <div>
        <div class="div2">
          Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long
          text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text
          goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes
          here...

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
     <div class="div1">
      <div>
        <div class="div2">
          Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long
          text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text
          goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes here... Really long text goes
          here...

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



.div1 {
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}
.div1>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: the question is why floating and why absolute ? ... so everything is out of the flow and you make it harder for you

Comment: Could you provide an image of the desired layout? Thanks

Comment: This is part of a really complex cart. Ideally I just want the each div to stack on top of each other showing all the text.